# Prolog ECLiPSe - how to implement yield method?

Tags: c++, prolog, argument-passing

i'm using ECLiPSe programming logic system.

i want to implement the yield method for passing the values from prolog to C/C++.
Has anyone implemented it?

Are there any other ways for passing the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following page tells how to integrate ECLiPSe with C++ using the yield method:

http://87.230.22.228/doc/embedding/embroot006.html#toc8